# Rspec-rails: Testing if layout includes styles or javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rspec

I want to test if my 'style.css' is linked to my page while rendering it with a certain layout, for example 'application.html.erb':

So here's the spec:

**spec/views/layouts/application.html.erb_spec.rb**

```
  it 'should include styles for screen media' do
    render
    rendered.should have_selector('link',
      :href => '/stylesheets/style.css',
      :media => 'screen',
      :rel => 'stylesheet',
      :type => 'text/css'
    )
  end
```

And my application.html.erb looks like:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :style, :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run my view spec, it fails because

```
<link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1289599022" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

is rendered, and

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='/stylesheets/reset.css'/>
```

is expected.

And it's all about the numbers '?1289599022' rails adding after the filename. Any ideas on how to test this functionality?

Comment: given the spec you showed, I don't think your expectation would be what you wrote.

Comment: this spec really looks for a proper link tag according to the rspec console output

Comment: Is it capybara? How did you get it work in view specs? http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/6f8188ba35e170ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Rails **stylesheet_path()** helper instead... this will generate the URL with the timestamp for you.

```
it 'renders a link to the stylesheet' do
  render
  rendered.should have_selector('link',
    :rel => 'stylesheet',
    :media => 'screen',
    :href => stylesheet_path('style')
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into the same problem today and it's been extremely frustrating. I tried the solution above but did not have access to the stylesheet_path (I am using an rspec controller test but am rendering the view directly from the controller test). I tried including the necessary module to make it work but that just gave me other errors. Eventually, I decided to just change rails in test mode such that it will not generate the asset timestamp.

Simply edit your test.rb to include the line:

ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID'] = ''

inside of

Testapp::Application.configure do
...
end